# .Net Maui: How to group Radio buttons inside a BindableLayout?

Tags: mvvm, radio-button, maui, bindable

I am working on a .Net Maui app where I have to use radio buttons to allow user to select an item from a list. This list is again a part of another list. The overall structure is like Item1(SubItem1,SubItem2,SubItem3,SubItem4), Item2((SubItem1,SubItem2,SubItem3,SubItem4), Item3((SubItem1,SubItem2,SubItem3,SubItem4), Item4((SubItem1,SubItem2,SubItem3,SubItem4)).

The itemsource (SubItem1,SubItem2,SubItem3,SubItem4) is same for all. I am using BindableLayout and ContentView to generate the view. I am sharing code issue reproduced in a sample app.
My requirement is to select a single SubItem for an Item and its value should be stored in a bindable property `SelectedItem`.

The issue I am facing is whenever I select a subitem say SubItem1 for a Item1 then selected item in all the remaining list Item2,Item3,Item4 also get updated with SubItem1.
I tried by making GroupName different for radio buttons and binding it. This is causing the issue that if I select one of the radio button then `RadioButton_CheckedChanged` event is called 4 times.
I have to avoid mutiple calls here.

Can someone suggest where I am doing wrong?

Code for BindableLayout MainPage

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MauiSampleApp.Views.RadioButtonPage"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MauiSampleApp.Controls"
    Title="RadioButtonPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Spacing="10">
        <VerticalStackLayout
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ModelItemList}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid
                        RowSpacing="6"
                        RowDefinitions="20,auto">

                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Text="{Binding Title}"/>

                        <controls:RadioButtonContentView
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            GroupName="{Binding Title}"
                            ItemSource="{Binding ItemList}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Code Behind for MainPage

```
public partial class RadioButtonPage : ContentPage
{
    private RadioButtonViewModel viewModel { get; set; }
    public RadioButtonPage()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel = new RadioButtonViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel for MainPage

```
public class RadioButtonViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private List<ModelClass> _modelItemList = new();
    public List<ModelClass> ModelItemList
    {
        get => _modelItemList;
        set => SetProperty(ref _modelItemList, value);
    }

    private PickerItem _selectedItem;
    public PickerItem SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
    }

    public List<PickerItem> RadioButtonList { get; set; }

    public RadioButtonViewModel()
    {
        RadioButtonList = new()
        {
            new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem1", IsSelected = true },
            new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem2", IsSelected = false },
            new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem3", IsSelected = false },
            new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem4", IsSelected = false }
        };

        ModelItemList = new()
        {
            new ModelClass { Title = "Item1", ItemList = RadioButtonList, SelectedItem = RadioButtonList[0] },
            new ModelClass { Title = "Item2", ItemList = RadioButtonList, SelectedItem = RadioButtonList[1] },
            new ModelClass { Title = "Item3", ItemList = RadioButtonList, SelectedItem = RadioButtonList[2] },
            new ModelClass { Title = "Item4", ItemList = RadioButtonList, SelectedItem = RadioButtonList[3] }
        };
    }
}
```

Models used:

1. ModelClass

```
public class ModelClass : ObservableObject
{
    private string _title = "";
    public string Title
    {
        get => _title;
        set => SetProperty(ref _title, value);
    }

    private List<PickerItem> _itemList = new();
    public List<PickerItem> ItemList
    {
        get => _itemList;
        set => SetProperty(ref _itemList, value);
    }
    
    private PickerItem _selectedItem;
    public PickerItem SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
    }
}
```

2. PickerItem

```
public class PickerItem : ObservableObject
{
    private string _key = "";
    public string Key
    {
        get => _key;
        set => SetProperty(ref _key, value);
    }

    private bool _isSelected = false;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set => SetProperty(ref _isSelected, value);
    }
}
```

Code for RadioButtonContentView:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiSampleApp.Controls.RadioButtonContentView"
             x:Name="this">

    <VerticalStackLayout
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource, Source={x:Reference this}}"
        RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="{Binding GroupName, Source={x:Reference this}}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid
                    ColumnSpacing="12"
                    ColumnDefinitions="20,*">

                    <RadioButton
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                        Value="{Binding .}"
                        CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged"/>

                    <Label
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Text="{Binding Key}"/>

                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Code behind for RadioButtonContentView

```
public partial class RadioButtonContentView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(SelectedItem),
        typeof(PickerItem),
        typeof(RadioButtonContentView),
        null,
        propertyChanged: SelectedItemPropertyChanged);

    public PickerItem SelectedItem
    {
        get => (PickerItem)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    private static void SelectedItemPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (oldValue is PickerItem oldPickerItem)
        {
            oldPickerItem.IsSelected = false;
        }

        if (newValue is PickerItem newPickerItem)
        {
            newPickerItem.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(ItemSource),
        typeof(List<PickerItem>),
        typeof(RadioButtonContentView),
        new List<PickerItem>());

    public List<PickerItem> ItemSource
    {
        get => (List<PickerItem>)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty GroupNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(GroupName),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(RadioButtonContentView),
        "");

    public string GroupName
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(GroupNameProperty);
        set => SetValue(GroupNameProperty, value);
    }

    public RadioButtonContentView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is RadioButton radioButton)
        {
            if (e.Value)
            {
                var selectedPickerItem = radioButton.Value;
                SelectedItem = (PickerItem)selectedPickerItem;
            }
        }
    }

    void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Parameter is PickerItem selectedPickerItem)
        {
            SelectedItem = selectedPickerItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you shared, I found you have missed property `SelectedItem` for `ModelClass.cs` while initializing the variable `ModelItemList`.

So, I added such variable for `ModelClass.cs`, just as follows:

```
public  class ModelClass: ObservableObject
{
    private string _title = "";
    public string Title
    {
        get => _title;
        set => SetProperty(ref _title, value);
    }

    // add property SelectedItem here
    private PickerItem _selectedItem =new();
    public PickerItem SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
    }

    private List<PickerItem> _itemList = new();
    public List<PickerItem> ItemList
    {
        get => _itemList;
        set => SetProperty(ref _itemList, value);
    }

    public ModelClass(string title, List<PickerItem> items, int selectedItemIndex)
    {
        this._title = title;
        this._itemList = items;
        this._selectedItem = _itemList[selectedItemIndex];

        //set selected item for each group 
        if (selectedItemIndex >=0 && selectedItemIndex < _itemList.Count)
        {
            ItemList[selectedItemIndex].IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Besides,we also need to use the different list instance `RadioButtonList`  for `RadioButtonViewModel.cs`, just as Nikos said. And the `SelectedItem` should be an element of the `ItemList` for each `ModelClass` instance. The way you used was not in the right way.

You can refer to the following code:

```
 public partial class RadioButtonViewModel: ObservableObject
   {
       private List<ModelClass> _modelItemList = new();
       private object ItemList;

       public List<ModelClass> ModelItemList
       {
           get => _modelItemList;
           set => SetProperty(ref _modelItemList, value);
       }


       public RadioButtonViewModel()
       {

           ModelItemList = new()
       {
       new ModelClass ( "Item1",GetNewRadioButtonList() ,0),
       new ModelClass ("Item2", GetNewRadioButtonList() ,1),
       new ModelClass ("Item3", GetNewRadioButtonList(), 2),
       new ModelClass ("Item4", GetNewRadioButtonList(), 3)

       };

         List<PickerItem> GetNewRadioButtonList()
           {
               return new List<PickerItem>
      {
         new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem1", IsSelected = false },
         new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem2", IsSelected = false },
         new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem3", IsSelected = false },
         new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem4", IsSelected = false }
      };
           }
       }
   }
```

**Note:**

I modified the way of setting the selectedItem, you can check the added constructor method of `ModelClass`:

```
  public ModelClass(string title, List<PickerItem> items, int selectedItemIndex)
    {
        this._title = title;
        this._itemList = items;
        this._selectedItem = _itemList[selectedItemIndex];

        //set selected item for each group 
        if (selectedItemIndex >=0 && selectedItemIndex < _itemList.Count)
        {
            ItemList[selectedItemIndex].IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code you use the same list Instance **RadioButtonList** from your **RadioButtonViewModel**.

```
RadioButtonList = new()
        {
            new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem1", IsSelected = true },
            new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem2", IsSelected = false },
            new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem3", IsSelected = false },
            new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem4", IsSelected = false }
        };

        ModelItemList = new()
        {
            new ModelClass { Title = "Item1", ItemList = RadioButtonList, SelectedItem = RadioButtonList[0] },
            new ModelClass { Title = "Item2", ItemList = RadioButtonList, SelectedItem = RadioButtonList[1] },
            new ModelClass { Title = "Item3", ItemList = RadioButtonList, SelectedItem = RadioButtonList[2] },
            new ModelClass { Title = "Item4", ItemList = RadioButtonList,SelectedItem = RadioButtonList[3] }
        };
```

To solve this issue, you need to ensure each **ModelClass** instance has its own copy of the list of **PickerItems**. This way, changing the selected radio button in one group doesn't affect the other groups. Here's how you can adjust your **ViewModel** to create separate instances of **PickerItem** lists for each **ModelClass**:

```
public RadioButtonViewModel()
{
    ModelItemList = new List<ModelClass>
    {
        new ModelClass { Title = "Item1", ItemList = GetNewRadioButtonList(), SelectedItem = RadioButtonList[0] },
        new ModelClass { Title = "Item2", ItemList = GetNewRadioButtonList(), SelectedItem = RadioButtonList[1] },
        new ModelClass { Title = "Item3", ItemList = GetNewRadioButtonList(), SelectedItem = RadioButtonList[2] },
        new ModelClass { Title = "Item4", ItemList = GetNewRadioButtonList(), SelectedItem = RadioButtonList[3] }
    };


    private List<PickerItem> GetNewRadioButtonList()
    {
       return new List<PickerItem>
       {
          new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem1", IsSelected = false },
          new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem2", IsSelected = false },
          new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem3", IsSelected = false },
          new PickerItem { Key = "SubItem4", IsSelected = false }
       };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nikos, the grouping of radio buttons are working properly with the above solution.